# Number of substrings starting and ending with '1'

Tags: c++, string, c++11, substring

I'm trying to find the number of substrings that start and end with '1' where input string are numbers like 1111, 10001 etc. Given code does not show correct output but if I replace getline with cin as the input method the code works fine. It also works if I skip input of n (n is the length of the string to be entered) and use i<str.length() in for loop. Why does this happen?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
    
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string str;
    getline(cin,str);
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    if(str[i]=='1')
    c++;
    c=c*(c+1)/2;
    cout<<c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger too see the value of `str`, or dump it `std::cout << "'" << str << "'\n";` before the loop

Comment: @S.M. I did try doing that but as far as I'm understanding the above code skipped `getline` for some reason and so there was no output for `str`. But this does not happen with `cin`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `getline` reads all characters after `n` until the end of the line including spaces. So the length of your `str` will be equal to n+1 because of the space in the beginning.

How to fix (for example): `for(int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)`

Comment: I tried doing that but I'm still facing the same issue. In fact, when I'm using `getline` instead of `cin` I'm not even able to input `str`. That part of the code is getting skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues with the shared code are:

1. Collecting input in variable ‘n’ first and then assigning it to a string variable via getline() seems redundant. The expected work can be done with the usage of single getline() statement : “getline(cin,str);”
2. The usage of variable ‘n’ in the for loop: the variable ‘n’ is to get the length of the input string (so that the loop can compare all elements of the string with number ‘1’. as per the shared code you are trying to execute the for loop for ‘n’ numbers of time which I believe is not the expectation here.)
   e.g: if the string input is “111”, then the loop will get executed for 111 times where it should run for 3 times (please correct if my understanding of the motive of the code is different here )
   Present loop condition check will surely give the “string subscript out of range” assertion failure.

   int n;
   cin >> n;
   string str;
   getline(cin, str);
   int c = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   { }

As per my understating , above code lines can be replaced by below chunk of code.

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
int c = 0;
int n = str.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{}
```

Comment: `n` takes in the size of `str`. So if `str` is to be '1111' then `n` would be '4' (I have edited the question for better understanding). But even with this input I'm failing to get the desired ouput. I know if I skip input of `n` it will  work. But I want to know why this does not work as it seems logically right to me.